# Round up or down to closest 20

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As the question suggests, I need to round up or down to closest 20, with the exception of numbers from 0-14, all must round to 20, because no zero values are allowed.The table has not to be updated with new values.For now I have managed only rounding up or down to the nearest 100 as seen below:

```
 CASE WHEN ROUND(number,-2)=0 THEN CAST(ROUND(number,-2)+100 AS DECIMAL(18, 0)) 
      ELSE CAST(ROUND(number,-2) AS DECIMAL(18,0)) END AS [NUMBER]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @testValue Int = 35;

SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN @testValue BETWEEN 0 AND 14 THEN 20
    ELSE ROUND((@testValue * 1.0) / 20, 0) * 20
  END MyRoundedValue;
```

There may be a more optimal approach, but this was the first solution that came to mind. The `* 1.0` is to force conversion to a floating point number so that the `/ 20` will produce fractional results. The result is rounded using `ROUND` then multiplied back by `20` to get your final "rounded" value.

*Edited to take your special case of `0-14` into account...*

Comment: Dividing by 20.0 will force a floating point number.  You don't need to multiple by 1.0

Comment: So, it's basically the same idea.  But yes, it could also be written `ELSE ROUND(@testValue / 20.0, 0) * 20`. If `20` is a variable that's also `Int` you'll require the `* 1.0` again.

Comment: I do not have any idea why sometimes the result is 1 or 2( with different values btw, 19;29;16 etc.). but i modified the code with the format described in my question and it worked very well.Thanks a lot, I didn't think of multiplying with 1.0 .

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
--N = Your nearest number
--X = Number to round
SELECT ROUND(X/N, 0) * N
```

Example Usage:

```
DECLARE @numberToRound INT;
SET @numberToRound = 25;

CASE WHEN @numberToRound BETWEEN 0 AND 14 THEN
    20
ELSE
    ROUND((CAST(@numberToRound AS DECIMAL) / 20.00), 0) * 20
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer integer division<sup>*</sup> where possible, and if `number` is an integer, my solution would probably be something like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN number BETWEEN 0 AND 14 THEN 20  /* actually, it seems to make more sense
                                           to have the range as BETWEEN 0 AND 9,
                                           because values from 10 to 14 would be
                                           converted to 20 with the ELSE branch
                                           anyway */
  ELSE (number + 10) / 20 * 20
END
```

---

<sub>*<sup>*</sup>SQL Server uses integer division when both operands are integer.*</sub>