# Round to the nearest odd integer in SQL

Tags: sql, rounding

I've found myself somewhat improbably* needing to round to the nearest ODD integer in SQL.  There's a nice solution for how to round to the nearest N (2,5,10,etc) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605007/round-up-or-down-to-closest-20), but  nothing explicitly on odd numbers.  Using Oracle 11gR2, if there are solutions particular to Oracle out there.

*Need to join my data to tables stripped from this [study](http://www.nwea.org/sites/www.nwea.org/files/resources/2012%20RIT%20Scale%20School%20Norms%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf).  The authors used a consistent bin width of 2...but sometimes it's even, and others it's odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an oracle PL/SQL Function that would do that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ROUNDODD 
(
  IMPNUM IN NUMBER  
) RETURN NUMBER AS
roundnum number;
oddnum number;
BEGIN
roundnum := round (IMPNUM,0);

IF mod(roundnum,2) = 1
THEN RETURN roundnum;
ELSE
IF roundnum > IMPNUM
THEN RETURN roundnum-1;
ELSE RETURN roundnum+1;
end if;
end if;
END ROUNDODD;
```

Comment: i tested it in SQL developer and it seems to handle all positive cases I could think of well

Comment: does DCP's answer pass your test cases?  Misbehaving on my data.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by DCP?

Comment: should have been more clear - another answer on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/11004077/561698

Comment: No, his script doesnt account for numbers like 15.9, he is missing a case to check if the rounded number is greater than the input number thus subtract by one rather than add by one

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for negative numbers. How can I fix this so it does?

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
DECLARE
  n FLOAT;
BEGIN  
   n := 195.8;
   SELECT 
      CASE
         WHEN mod(FLOOR(n),2) = 0 THEN FLOOR(n)+1
         ELSE FLOOR(n)
      END NUM
      INTO n
   FROM DUAL;
   dbms_output.put_line(to_char(n));
   END;
/
```

Sometimes straightfoward is best, as people who come along after you will understand what's going on.

Comment: Might be missing something, but not sure that this works - it rounded 195.8 to 197, and under my 'round to nearest odd' I would want that to go to 195.

Comment: @Andrew - Yes, I misunderstood the requirement. See latest edit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need a case statement, this should do it:

```
SELECT 
   ROUND((11.9-1)/2,0)*2+1
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 3):

Arithmetic OR?

```
ROUND(3.14,0)|1
```

**EDIT**

Andriy correctly corrects this to `FLOOR(3.64)::int|1`. (which works [correctly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/302)).

Comment: Close, but not correct. 1. Both operands of `|` should be `int` (the result of your `ROUND()` isn't). 2. What do you think `ROUND(3.64,0)::int|1` would evaluate to?

Comment: Well, `FLOOR()` doesn't accept a second parameter, [as you can see for yourself](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/301), but [without it, everything's fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/302), [same as with `TRUNC()`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/306), which, incidentally, [does accept a second parameter](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/305). By the way, did I tell you [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) is a great tool for testing small solutions like yours? :)

Comment: P.S. Note, though, that `TRUNC()` and `FLOOR()` work differently on negatives, because, strictly speaking, they perform different functions: the latter rounds the value down to the nearest integer, while the former simply truncates the part after the specified decimal digit (or, if not specified, just truncates the decimal part). Thus, `FLOOR(-3.64)` evaluates to `-4` (because `-4 < -3.64`), while `TRUNC(-3.64)` to `-3`. If negatives are possible, this should be taken into consideration.

Comment: Andriy, thanks for the tip on sqlfiddle.  And clearly I have no business answering SQL questions ;)

Comment: Ah, but I still consider your idea of using bitwise `OR` great anyway. And since you've added a working solution, this deserves a +1. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

using modulus can help you find even/odd numbers. add 1 to the even numbers

```
select
    case when (value % 2) <> 0 then value
    else value + 1 end
from table
```